# Get the intersection iteratively

Tags: c++

```
intersection.clear();
int a = distance(leftbound, rightbound);
{
    set_intersection(leftbound, rightbound, k[str.substr(start_location, i - start_location)].begin(),
         k[str.substr(start_location, i - start_location)].end(), back_inserter(intersection));
}
vector<int> test;
vector<int>::iterator test_it1 = test.begin();
vector<int>::iterator test_it2 = intersection.begin();
test.resize(intersection.size());
for (; test_it1 != test.end(); test_it1++)
{
    *test_it1 = *test_it2;
    test_it2++;
}
leftbound = test.begin();
rightbound = test.end();
```

`k[...]` will change with `i`; I believe we can ignore it.

The difficulty to me is how to save the results for the calculated intersection.

So I'm trying to find the intersection iteratively, but the compiler keeps outputting `vector iterators incompatible`.
The basic thought is: first I find the intersection of first two, then I save the intersection result and `set_intersection` with the third one, etc. But it seems not to work, which is really confusing.

Comment: I have deleted the line test.resize(intersection.size());, it can compile but the result is still not true, why would that happen?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Please do not tag code that is clearly and exclusively C++ with the C tag; that annoys the locals on the C tag.  Please do make sure you read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  I don't think there's enough context in the code and question for people to be able to discern what you're trying to do — let alone what you're doing wrong,  Finally, don't add comments to elucidate your question; edit the question to include the extra information.  You can edit your own question.